# Java algorithm to group objects based on matching properties

Tags: java, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I want to implement java code to group items based on similar attributes. Say I have arrays of customers which stores followin information Name , City , Language , Car , Company

```
Customer1= { Mahesh, Mumbai , Hindi , Maruti , Infy}
Customer2= { Robin, Mumbai, English , Honda , Wipro}
Customer3 = { Mahek, Mumbai, Hindi, Maruti, Wipro}
Customer4 = { Rohit, Mumbai, English, Honda, Infy}
Customer5 = { Yogesh, Delhi, English, Honda, ''}
Customer6 = { Alpesh, Delhi, English, '', TCS}
Customer7 = { Mark, Delhi, English, '', WIPRO}
```

Now what I am looking for is that I can create group of these customers who have similar City, Language and Car

So I should have 4 groups

```
Group 1 = Customer1 , Customer3
Group 2 = Customer2 , Customer4 
GROUP 3 = Customer5 
Group 4 = Customer6 ,Customer7
```

Basically I want to group items based on some similar properties. How I can achieve this efficiently in Java

Comment: That, and group how (ie, how do you wish to retrieve items in different groups)? There is an "easy" `Map`-based solution for that.

Comment: Try yo construct different sets of words from a dictionary, reorder properties of each object and after compare that instances with sets.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you mean group by **matching properties**, not **similar properties**. The difference is great and this problem is quite simpler.

I would suggest you sort all the items on the three criteria and then just group the items in a single pass. Simply add the current item to the current group if it matches all 3 properties, otherwise place it in a new group on its own and name this group "current group".

Another option would be to hash the objects using the three properties and create groups out of the objects with equal hash(you will have to device a way to handle collisions and there are numerous ways to do that). As it seems that the values of the properties you care to use for the grouping are enumerated you may even be able to avoid collisions(if the possible combinations are few enough).

Comment: +1 I agree. If you want *similar properites* k-means algorithm could do it for you.